# How to use reactive form when our default form data is async in angular 5?

Tags: angular, forms

I am creating a form to edit something, I request an object from server and the server answers me with a promise and I will put the data in the fields default value.
But because the object is async, angular can't put the default value in form so it throw error:

```
  editUser = new FormGroup({});

  constructor(private User: UserInfoService)   { }

  ngOnInit() {

    this.User.getUser(2)

      .then((res) => {

      console.log(res.first_name);

      this.editUser = new FormGroup({

        name: new FormControl(res.first_name)

      });

    });

  }
```

It should put the value from getUser in forms default value but the data isn't ready at beginning and angular throw error:
`Error: Cannot find control with name: 'name'`
what is the solution?

Comment: create formGroup with controls and validation and on response set value using `this.editUser.controls['name'].setValue(response.name);`

Comment: Hey! Did either answer help you or need further assistance? :)

Answer (score 2):

As you noticed, the template is rendered before form is built, thus the error, since form does not exist when template is rendered. You can solve this by either build an empty form initially, then patch the values when you get them, or them set an `if` condition on your form to not render it until values are set. Here is though option for building empty form intially:

```
constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
  this.editUser = fb.group({
    name: ['']
  })
}
```

and when you get the values:

```
.then((res) => {
  console.log(res.first_name);
  this.editUser.setValue({
    name: res.first_name
  })
})
```

Answer (score 1):

This issue happens when you try to select some value which is dependent on your api, and unfortunately in angularjs2 we do not have privilege to set your value on promise. You can achieve this with settime out function.

```
.then((res) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
          (<FormControl>controls['name'])
            .setValue(res.first_name, {onlySelf: false});
        }, 0);
 })
```

Comment: Where would you put this timeout? And how does it solve the issue? :)

Comment: Check now..It should be in your subscribe function.